# How to generate 8 digit of unique number with Spring Boot and MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data-mongodb 1.5.6 and MongoDb 4.
I want to save minimum 6 and maximum 10 digits of unique number in sequence order for student in 'rollNumber' field.

For example previously in hibernate I used JPA - @SequenceGenerator to generate rollnumber in sequence like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create **“sequence” collection** in your MongoDB.

```
db.sequence.insert({_id: "hosting",seq: 0})
```

Same you can refer in your code.

Reference : https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-auto-sequence-id-example/

Comment: In reference he updated _id, I want _id as it is and save roll number in another field like 'rollNumber'.